# Need to reload page for show new value of meta_key in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I tried to `update meta key` with custom form in `wordpress`

**CMS**: Wordpress

**Plugin**: advanced custom fields

**Field Type**: Repeater field

**this is a code in single.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if( have_rows('custom_req') ){
    while( have_rows('custom_req') ){ the_row(); 
      $r_req = get_sub_field('req_fie');
      if ($_POST['radio-b'] == $r_req ) { 
        update_sub_field('rq_answer', 'new_value');
      }
    }
  }
}
if( have_rows('custom_req') ){
  while( have_rows('custom_req') ){ the_row(); 
    the_sub_field('rq_answer'); // This line shows the previous value
  }
}
```

the problem is shows the **previous value**, and the page must be **reloaded** to show the new value

Why is that? How do I solve this problem?

Thanks for any help

Comment: _Why is that?_ - because by the time this template is read, the PHP has already interacted with the data from the database. So, the PHP sends the data to update the sub field, but it had already retrieved the data for the next loop. _How do I solve this problem?_ - you will have to use AJAX if you don't want a page refresh.

Comment: I think ajax is better than refresh page, how to use ajax for this form? `<form id="form1" action="" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit1" name="submit2"></form>`

Comment: We're not going to code something for you. There are plenty of tutorials to use AJAX and Forms in WP. I would suggest you start there, and come back here and ask another question if you get stuck.